# How do I solve an "InvalidCastException" in C#?

Tags: c#, forms, casting, picturebox

I am getting a run-time error which tells me that it is unable to cast an object of type PictureBox to type MusicNote (MusicNote inherits from PictureBox.)

```
private void Note_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //try
        //{
            foreach (MusicNote mn in panel2.Controls) //this is where the error occurs
            {
                if (sender == mn)
                {
                    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
                    {
                        count = 0;
                        timer1.Start();
                        sp.SoundLocation = MusicNote_path + mn.note + ".wav";
                        sp.Play();
                    }
                if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
                {
                    dragging = true;
                    mn.BackColor = Color.HotPink;


                }
```

Below is a part of the MusicNote class, including the constructor, to show what happens each time a MusicNote is constructed:

```
class MusicNote : PictureBox
{
    public int notepitch;
    public int noteduration;
    public String noteshape;
    public String note;
    enum Accid { sharp, flat, sole };

    public static String NoteImage_path = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\Notes-Images\\";
    public static int xLoc = 30;
    public int yLoc = 0;

    System.Timers.Timer timer1 = new System.Timers.Timer();

    public MusicNote(int iNotepitch, int iDuration, String iBnoteShape, String iNote)
    {
        notepitch = iNotepitch;
        noteduration = iDuration;
        noteshape = iBnoteShape;
        note = iNote;


        ImageLocation =  NoteImage_path + noteshape + ".bmp";
        BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        ClientSize = new Size(35, 35);
        //BringToFront();


        Location = new Point(xLoc, getyLoc(iNote));
        xLoc += 37;
    }
```

This is how the panel is being populated:

```
MusicNote mn = new MusicNote(mk.getMusicNote(), duration, bNoteShape, mk.getNote());
mn.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(Note_MouseDown);
mn.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(Note_MouseUp);
mn.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(Note_MouseClick);

panel2.Controls.Add(mn); //adding MusicNote component to MusicStaff (panel2) collection
```

Edit: You can view the error [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCw5Z.jpg).

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: Maybe there's other things than MusicNote's in that list of controls?

Comment: @MarioMitterbauer image added, you can view it at the bottom of the question

Comment: @PMF I don’t know what you mean?

Comment: `MusicNote` is more specific than `PictureBox` so you cannot cast a `PictureBox` to a `MusicNote` since not every `PictureBox` is a `MusicNote`. You can cast the other way from `MusicNote` to `PictureBox`. Every dog is an animal but every animal is not a dog.

Comment: @LukeXuereb the panel is full of PictureBoxes, am I right? Instead of this PicturBoxes you should add the `MusicNote`.

Comment: @CodingYoshi but I don’t believe I ever cast a picturebox to a music note though.

Comment: Can you share the code that is populating the panel?

Comment: That's what the error says. The controls in `panel2` are not all `MusicNote` so when you loop and do `MusicNote mn in panel2.Controls` you are implicitly casting.

Comment: @JoshKnack done.

Comment: @CodingYoshi so in order to run a foreach loop for music notes, the panel2.Controls must consist of only Music Notes?

Comment: Why do you need the `foreach` loop at all?

Comment: @DavidTansey without the foreach loop how can the program distinguish one music note’s attributes from another’s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To loop over `MusicNote` instances only, you can use the `OfType` extension method from LINQ:

```
foreach (MusicNote mn in panel2.Controls.OfType<MusicNote>()) {
   // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

When your program gets control in an event handler like `Note_MouseDown` you receive a reference to the control that 'took' the event in the UI (`object sender`).

Try casting the `sender` to `MusicNote` using the `as` clause.  If the cast is not possible (because `sender` is something other than `MusicNote`) the use of the `as` clause does not throw an exception -- instead it just hands you a NULL reference, which you can test for.

Try something like this:

```
private void Note_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var mn = sender as MusicNote;
    if (mn != null) 
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            count = 0;
            mn.timer1.Start();
            sp.SoundLocation = MusicNote_path + mn.note + ".wav";
            sp.Play();
        }
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            dragging = true;
            mn.BackColor = Color.HotPink;
        }
    }
}
```

You really don't need the `foreach`.

Comment: I'd probably just use a cast - if the event is only meant to be subscribed to the `MusicNote`, then if the cast fails, that indicates a bug and an exception is entirely reasonable at that point. But I agree that there's no need to use a foreach loop. (The OP is already using `sender` in the comparison, so it's not clear why they're looping at all.)

Answer (score 0):

This error occures every time when the `foreach (MusicNote mn in panel2.Controls)` loop find anything else then a `MusicNote`.

You can avoid that by looping all `Controls` like `foreach (Control cntrl in panel2.Controls)`

Example Code:

```
foreach (Control cntrl in panel2.Controls) 
            {
                if(cntrl is MusicNote)
                {
                     //do something with the MusicNote Control
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to fix your issue but let's just do a walkthrough of your code so you can see how clumsy it is. In plain English, you are doing this:

> The mouse button is pressed down on a control. Which control? Well the control in `sender`. You loop through all the controls in `panel2` to see if one of them is the `sender` and then you do some work.

But why would you loop through all the controls in `panel2`? When you created the `MusicNote` control, you created this event handler specifically for that control to inform you when the mouse is down on it. And now the control is raising an event and saying "Hey, the mouse button is down and it is down on me!" You see, even though `panel2.Controls.OfType<MusicNote>()` will fix your issue, but why would you do that? It seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

The only reason you would do what you are doing is if you created the control, subscribed to the `MouseDown` event, then programmatically moved the control from one panel to another and you only want to do some work if the control happens to be in `panel2` when the mouse is down. I doubt you moved it around; and even if you did, there are better ways to handle that scenario.

**Proper Solution**

You do not need a loop and all you need is this:

```
private void Note_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // If neither right nor left is down, return immediately because nothing needs 
    // to be done.
    if (!(e.Button == MouseButtons.Right || e.Button == MouseButtons.Left))
    {
        return;
    }

    // This should not fail, if it does, then ask yourself why have you created 
    // this handler for things which are not MusicNote.
    MusicNote mn = (MusicNote)sender;

    // Do some work below
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        count = 0;
        timer1.Start();
        sp.SoundLocation = MusicNote_path + mn.note + ".wav";
        sp.Play();
    }

    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        dragging = true;
        mn.BackColor = Color.HotPink;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This error occurs when `panel2.Controls` contains `Controls` not only of the type `MusicNote` or `PictureBox`. From your data it is not clear what is the type of all `panel2.Controls`, should be solely `Collection` or `List` of PictureBoxes. If `panel2.Controls` contains any `Control` of a type different from `Picturebox` or `MusicNote` (e.g. `TextBox`, etc.), you get the error. If the types of all `panel2.Controls` are correct, then most likely the `panel2` is not fully loaded when the error occurs.
You may try:

```
foreach (var mn in panel2.Controls)
if (sender == (MusicNote)mn)
```

Comment: Looks like you are trying to cast the `Controls` *collection* to a `MusicNote` -- I don't think that will work.

Comment: @Codigo better you change `MusicNote` to `Control` within the foreach loop and catch the `MusicNote` with a if condition within the loop.